# Problem with Ruby string concatenation

Tags: ruby, string

This works

```
irb(main):001:0> name = "Rohit " "Sharma"
=> "Rohit Sharma"
```

But this doesn't

```
irb(main):001:0> fname = "Rohit "
=> "Rohit "
irb(main):002:0> lname = "Sharma"
=> "Sharma"
irb(main):003:0> name = fname lname
```

It gives this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `fname' for main:Object
from (irb):3
```

Please provide some suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

After getting the answers I have written a [blog post](http://rohitsharma9889.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/string-concatenation-in-ruby/). Please check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is related to the fact that `fname` would have to be a function for this to work. Instead, try

```
name = fname + lname
```

or even

```
name = "#{fname}#{lname}"
```

but where you had

```
name = "Rohit " "Sharma"
```

it is a special case, since Ruby will join the two strings automatically.

Comment: Or `name = fname << lname` if you know the quirks.

Comment: Yes, that's the quirk. It's faster though.

Comment: why doesn't this work lname=" Sharma" name="Rohit" lname and gives SyntaxError. Please explain.

Comment: @Rohit: by default, you must use a `+`. The only situation where you can avoid it is with two double quoted strings next to each other. In the case you mention, you therefore need `name = "Rohit" + lname`. Hope this clears it up for you. In fact, always use `+` and you will be fine - there's no need to skip the `+`, even in the case `name = "Rohit " + "Sharma"`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
name = "Rohit " "Sharma"
```

You don't create two `String`s objects that then merge together to create one string. Instead, the Ruby (interpreter/compiler/whatever) looks at the code, and merges it together before producing a single `String` object.

So you can do

```
name = "Rohit " "Sharma"
```

but not

```
first_name_plus_space = "Rohit "
last_name = "Sharma"
name = first_name_plus_space last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `+` inbetween them like

```
name = fname + lname
```

`string + string` is defined to return a new string containing the two inputs concatenated together.