# How can I trace string creation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, trace

In [this answer to a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364344/problem-with-ruby-string-concatenation/4372002#4372002), I said that if you do

```
name = "Rohit " "Sharma"
```

you don't create two `String` objects with the contents `"Rohit "` and `"Sharma"` that combine to create a new String object with the contents `"Rohit Sharma"`, but that you only create a single String object to start off with.

But it's only a book telling me that, rather than manually verifying it.

How would you be able to log the creation of a String?

I tried using

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname
}

string = "Insert content here"
```

But only got

```
c-return -:3  set_trace_func   Kernel
    line -:5
```

And "Programming Ruby 1.9" (the Pickaxe) says that modifying `Class#new` wouldn't work for strings, as they're constructed without using `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't trace string creation as such, but the following suggests that the concatenation occurs before any string objects are created:

The following (I read about this in the Pickaxe, in the section "Behind the Curtain: The Ruby VM") works in YARV - I don't think it'd work in any other implementations of ruby:

```
irb(main):003:0> uncompiled_code = 'name = "Rohit " "Sharma"'
=> "name = \"Rohit \" \"Sharma\""
irb(main):004:0> code = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(uncompiled_code)
=> <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<compiled>@<compiled>>
irb(main):005:0> puts code.disassemble
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<compiled>@<compiled>>==========
local table (size: 2, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1] s1)
[ 2] name
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putstring        "Rohit Sharma"
0004 dup
0005 setlocal         name
0007 leave
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't log this, since this concatenation doesn't happen at runtime. It happens at parse time.

In other words: regardless of whatever code you write to log this, the concatenation will have happened long before your code ever gets run.

In yet other words: you trust that there's only one string object created the same way that you trust that `42` only creates one `Fixnum` object with the value `42`, not 42 `Fixnum` objects with the value `1`: the ISO Ruby Language Specification says so, and the source code of every single existing Ruby implementation says so, and every Ruby book ever written says so.

Comment: I agree that the concatenation happens at parse time, but wouldn't the creation of the concatenated String object happen at runtime?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Probably. Note, however, that object creation is not one of the 8 events that you can trace. You can only trace calling a Ruby method, returning from a Ruby method, calling a native operation (C function in MRI, YARV, C++ method in Rubinius and so on), returning from a native operation, start of a module definition, end of a module definition, raising an exception and executing a line.