# Ruby: Can you override "X" "x" "X" #=> "XxX"

Tags: ruby, string

Which method is executed when you do "X" "x" "X" #=> "XxX" ?
Can you override it?

Comment: Cool, I never would have dreamed that "x" "y" gives "xy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no method involved, it's just the Ruby interpreter concatenating strings.
And since there is no method involved, you can't override it.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364344/problem-with-ruby-string-concatenation) that is really worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a function - the parser concatenates adjacent string **literals**, so you can do:

```
"a" "b"
```

but not:

```
a = "a"; b = "b"; a b
```

I couldn't find documentation, but here are a couple references discussing the feature:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/143266

http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1585

http://pivotallabs.com/users/jpignata/blog